# Different probabilities output in logistic regression - sklearn and Stata

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statistics, stata, logistic-regression

this is the first time I have tried to use logistic regression in python and I ran into a serious problem.

The result that interests me is not zero-one outputs meaning "decision" about the choice in logit. Rather, I would like to get the probabilities of selecting an option. And I also have probabilities output from Stata for comparison.

I have three lists with data: scLL, scLL2, and scLLchoice. I read that Stata ignores NaN data, so because sometimes scLL and scLL2 may include NaN I tried two different approaches. I just deleted rows in scLL, scLL2, and scLLchoice if data in row was NaN. Another option was to use imputer - (as you can see in code ) but the effect was this same. Here is a code:

```
X=list(zip(scLL, scLL2))
y=scLLchoice
probStim2a=[]



imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=float("nan"), strategy='mean')
X_imputed = imputer.fit_transform(X)
logistic_regression= LogisticRegression()
logistic_regression.fit(X_imputed,y)
y_pred=logistic_regression.predict(X_imputed)


probStim2a=list(logistic_regression.predict_proba(X_imputed)[:,1])

for i in range(len(probStim2a)):
        print (probStim2a[i])
```

And this is part of my output:

```
0.5146826469187935
0.5891472587984292
0.596839657578841
0.5570721046966637
0.35240422902193136
```

The problem is that output from Stata is quite different:

```
0,5313423
0,6109276
0,6185878
0,5741577
0,3578928
```

I checked if inputs are the same (and they are).
I also tried to use statsmodel for comparison and once again I had different outputs (not only different than data from Stata, but also in comparison to sklearn outputs). Is it possible that these different tools generate so different outputs and it is not some error in my code? I know that this is operating on probabilities but still, 2 + 2 shouldn't equal 5 just because I used a different calculator...

What should I do?

Comment: these answers are for the exact same test set?

Comment: Yes, they are this same

Comment: If the inputs are being fed the same order and the parameters in both programs are the same and they both use same rounding approximation then they should be the same. otherwise there will be differences

Comment: at the end of the day the codes in each program are written differently minor changes over multiple iterations could cause a small change in final results . nothing to be worried about. in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

Well, arguably the results are not *that* different; they do bear a qualitative similarity, which implies some different setting between the two implementations.

The most probable suspect in this case is that sklearn's Logistic Regression (LR) by default uses the `penalty='l2'` argument ([docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html)); in other words, sklearn's implementation is not "vanilla" LR but actually *Ridge* LR. I am not familiar with Stata (and you do not post the relevant code), but from their own [documentation](http://wlm.userweb.mwn.de/Stata/wstatmnl.htm) it would seem that this is not the case here, hence the different results.

To obtain the same results, try removing the L2 penalty in sklearn, i.e.:

```
logistic_regression= LogisticRegression(penalty='none')
```

Regarding statsmodels, they have their own idiosyncratic defaults (namely without an intercept); see the Cross Validated thread [Logistic Regression: Scikit Learn vs Statsmodels](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203740/logistic-regression-scikit-learn-vs-statsmodels) for more details.

Comment: Thanks! I actually tried penalty='none' option. It does change outputs but they are still not the same as in Stata. Thanks to your link I was able to reproduce results from stats model by using (fit_intercept = False, C = 1e9) options.

Comment: @Kubaaaa the `C=1e9` argument should no longer be needed - `penalty='none'` (which was not available at the time of writing of the original answer - see update) should do the job.